# How to insert and view a date value by Native SQL?

Tags: abap, native-sql

I use the following ABAP code to insert a order:

```
EXEC SQL.
    INSERT INTO order VALUES('1','17/12/2012') //order id,order date
ENDEXEC.
```

But I got a runtime error. I try to change the date to `SYSDATE`

```
EXEC SQL.
    INSERT INTO order VALUES('1',SYSDATE)
ENDEXEC.
```

The error has fixed but I cannot get any value when I try to select a order date from order table.

```
DATA: oID(255).
DATA: oDate(255).
//select a order details where order id='1', and assign to oID,oDate
Write: /1 'Order date: ',oDate.
Write: /1 'Order ID: ',oID.
```

The output:

```
Order date: 
Order ID: 1
```

Comment: Why are you using NativeSQL instead of OpenSQL? The only reason to use NativeSQL is when you want to use any features which are exclusive to your database backend, but what you are doing here seems pretty generic.

Comment: I get your meaning, but how to insert a date value in NativeSQL?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to manipulate data using Native SQL, you have to use the native SQL dialect of the underlying DBMS. If you don't know that, you shouldn't be using Native SQL at all.

Comment: Even though you're right, these kind of snarky comments aren't particularly helpful, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: René: Probably an inavoidable by-product of having repaired a few messes left by people who thought they really needed Native SQL, GENERATE SUBROUTINE POOL and the likes too much... Sorry...

Comment: I know what you mean - dare I say most ABAP code is a big mess..? Luckily SO has a few active ABAP programmers who actually know their stuff :)

Comment: @René: Most ABAP code is average, but the big fsckups are usually made worse by using inappropriate techniques. "I don't understand the problem, so I probably have to use statements I don't understand either" or something like that...

Answer (score 3):

Put a colon (:) in front of variables:

```
EXEC SQL.
  INSERT INTO order VALUES('1', :sy-datum)
ENDEXEC.
```

Comment: A useful answer for me and I got this answer before a time. But anyway thanks a lot ;)